# Allowing single newlines?

Tags: discussion, markdown

Hi all..

Why is it that you can't do single-newlines? More often than not it bothers me not to be able to do so. Are there any reason it's been disallowed in the first place?

Answer (score 15):

It is not disallowed, and in fact very possible to do single-newlines,
just add 2 spaces after the previous line.

Alternatively, you can also use a `<br>` tag. 
Look at the [revision of this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/24551/list) for an example.

See also these links for more information regarding the Markdown editor:

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help
- [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user)

Comment: I never new about the two-spaces thing. Is that and HTML rendering convention or is it specific to these sites?

Comment: No, it is a Markdown thing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown

Comment: Didn't know that :) Why make it so subtle? :P

Comment: Markdown is subtle. I suppose that is what you get from a 'language' with no documentation.